# REGEX: Extract info from URL

Tags: php, regex, url, web-scraping

I have the following URL: [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zdz1zsG9L.*SR38,50*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zdz1zsG9L._SR38,50_.jpg)
I need to extract the image ID, that is 41zdz1zsG9L (just until the dot).
How do I do that with a regular expression?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https?:\/\/.*\/([^.]*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/32